# Identify a request is sent by a browser or another program

Tags: php, web

We are redirecting our users via Network Router to a page in which we have advertizements. But the problem is that when we redirect our users via Network Router to that page , all of their request on port 80 is redirected which means we get requests from all programs like messengers and...

We just want to identify that there is some one watching the advertisement and the request is not sent from any other program.

Till now we have tested some ways like captchas,getting user agents, using javascript and ajax but those ways did not solve the problem.

For captcha, we can not use one captcha per advertisement,that is not logical.

User agents can not be used because we can not get the list of correct user agents and the other problem is that some programs like messengers send IE user agent header.

The same for javascript is that some programs run javascript automatically especially those written via .Net.

Comment: And your question is: how to identify web page viewer?

Comment: you are correct. but I didnt find any good title.I will edit it now

Comment: `We are redirecting our users via Network Router to a page` Can you explain?

Comment: Try to play with [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV it can be easily faked by setting user agent in request headers.

Comment: @PLB that's obvious, but i can't imagine any other means to detect a browser with PHP ...

Comment: @hek2mgl We have a network and we are offering some free services on that.People who use our network will be redirected to our advertizement page each 15 min. Now we want to get sure that person has seen our advertizements.But when we redirect them, All of requests are redirected including requests from chat programs, updates and any other request on port 80

Comment: @Abadis **I would not doing this using an IP router**. You should use HTTP redirects using the `Location:` HTTP header

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for great answer.Some requests can not detect redirecting via router.For that reason we redirect them to a page and from there, we redirect them using HTTP redirect. Any other idea ?

Comment: @Abadis I'm really willing to help. But I need more information. Try to add an example to your question. With urls, ip's etc.